# Can I mine bitcoin with a gaming computer?

Tags: mining-hardware

Awhile ago i built a rather nice gaming computer it has
CPU: intel i5 6600k
GPU: Nvidia GTX 1080
Ram: 16 GB ddr4
PSU: corsair Ax1200W
Water cooled system

Would this be a decent mining machine. If so what would you predict its stats to be. What should I upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not profitable** to mine Bitcoin with computer(s) and GPU(s). If you just want to help secure the network and/or keep your place warm in a high-tech way, then you could mine Bitcoin ;)

It could be profitable for you to **mine some other coin**, using your computer and GPU(s). You could also set your computer up to **rent its computing power** to others by joining services like miningrigrentals.com

For GPU mining have in mind that **the more GPUs you have, the better**. Since you don't pay the cost of electricity, you might want to add more GPUs to your computer. Just make sure the Power Supply Unit (PSU) can handle them.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. The costs due to electricity consumption will make the effort useless.

At the moment, Bitcoin mining only works with latest generation ASICs in countries with electricity is cheap. If you want to mine with GPUs, Ethereum might be an alternative.

Comment: Would that machine be good for gpu mining what would the rates look like?

Comment: It will just depend on the GPU. Look for "ethereum mining calculator", you can also find the estimated hashrate for GTX 1080 online. It is said to reach around 20MH/s. All in all, it is not a lot of money and it will depend on the price of electricity.

Comment: I dont pay electricity.

Comment: Lucky you.... :)

Comment: Regarding upgrades: depending on the amount of PCI slots in your motherboard, you could buy a few more GPUs. CPU and memory dont really matter.

Comment: What does th/s mean?

Comment: What would you suggest as a good starter bitcoin machine i might actually see some revenue gain in?